# Update Duplicate Records (first mtch only) in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `result` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`lead_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO result (email, active) VALUES
('aaa@xxx.com', 1),
('aaa@xxx.com', 0),
('aaa@xxx.com', 0),
('aaa@xxx.com', 1),
('bbb@xxx.com', 1),
('bbb@xxx.com', 1),
('bbb@xxx.com', 0);


lead_id | email       | active
---------------------------
1       | aaa@xxx.com | 1
2       | aaa@xxx.com | 0
3       | aaa@xxx.com | 0
4       | aaa@xxx.com | 1
5       | bbb@xxx.com | 1
6       | bbb@xxx.com | 1
7       | bbb@xxx.com | 0
```

I need to update the table so that only one row or any set of matching email addresses is active

I am struggling to write a query to do this. It does not matter which row. The result would look like this

```
lead_id | email       | active
---------------------------
1       | aaa@xxx.com | 1
2       | aaa@xxx.com | 0
3       | aaa@xxx.com | 0
4       | aaa@xxx.com | 0
5       | bbb@xxx.com | 1
6       | bbb@xxx.com | 0
7       | bbb@xxx.com | 0
```

Thank you for your advice

Comment: you can do update based on lead_id ......update table_name set active =0 where lead_id in(4,6)

Comment: Is it possible to filter your data before sending it to SQL?  That way you wouldn't need to store useless rows.  AND you wouldn't have to worry about  crafting a query to do the job... just make sure you data is good coming in.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach sets `active` to `0` for any `lead_id`/`email` group which does not have the minimum `lead_id` value and is also active.  The `GROUP BY` subquery would have two records using your example data, for `lead_id` values of `1` and `5`.  The `result` table is then joined to this, and any record which does *not* match to the subquery has its `active` value set to `0`.  This is OK because either the value was already `0`, or it was a duplicate which we wish to remove.

```
UPDATE result AS r1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(lead_id) AS min_lead_id, email, active
    FROM result
    WHERE active = 1
    GROUP BY email, active
) AS r2
    ON r1.lead_id = r2.min_lead_id AND r2.email = r2.email
SET r1.active = 0
WHERE r2.active IS NULL
```